# Collision Detection that results in stopping a game and timer

Tags: java, collision-detection

So for a game I'm trying to have a user controlled image that runs away from a cpu controlled image. When they collide, I want the game to end and display how long they survived. I can't seem to get the images to stop when they collide, and the timer is not showing.

This is my user controlled image.

```
package parthap;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
public class Start {

    private int dx;
    private int dy;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Image image;
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
    protected boolean vis;

    public Start() {

        initCraft();
    }

    private void initCraft() {

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("donald.jpg");
        image = ii.getImage();
        width = image.getWidth(null);
        height = image.getHeight(null);
        x = 600;
        y = 400;        
    }

    public void move() {
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        checkOOB();
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    private void checkOOB() {
          if(x < 0) x = 0;
          if(x > 1200) x = 1200;
          if(y < 0) y = 0;
          if(y > 800) y = 800;
        }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = -5;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 5;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = -5;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            dy = 5;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            dy = 0;
        }
    }

    public boolean isVisible() {
        return vis;
    }

    public void setVisible(Boolean visible) {
        vis = visible;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

}
```

This is my AI

```
package parthap;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
public class AI_1 {
Random rand = new Random();

    // encapsulated data: instance data
    private int dx;
    private int dy;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Image image;
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
    protected boolean vis;

    // constructor
    public AI_1() {
        // initialize all instance data

    }
    // constructor ... overloaded because signature changed     
    public AI_1(int xpos, int ypos) {
        // initialize all instance data
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("kim (1).jpg");
        image = ii.getImage();
        x = xpos;
        y = ypos;      
    }

     protected void getImageDimensions() {

         width = image.getWidth(null);
         height = image.getHeight(null);
    }

    public void move() {
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        checkOOB();
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    private void checkOOB() {
        if(x < 0) x = 0;
        if(x > 1200) x = 1200;
        if(y < 0) y = 0;
        if(y > 800) y = 800;
    }

    /* the number generator for movement 
     * one parameter max to indicate the maximum number of case
     * statements representing the change in x and y, neg. and pos directions*/
    public void numbergen(int max, int speed) {

        int num = rand.nextInt(max)+1;

        switch (num){
        case 1:
                dx=-speed;
                break;
        case 2: 
                dx=speed;
                break;
        case 3: 
                dy=-speed;
                break;
        case 4: 
                dy=speed;
                break;
        default: 
                break;  
        }
    }
     public boolean isVisible() {
        return vis;
    }

    public void setVisible(Boolean visible) {
        vis = visible;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

}
```

And this is my board.

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private Timer timer;
    private Start start;
    private final int DELAY = 10;
    private final int B_WIDTH = 400;
    private final int B_HEIGHT = 300;
    private AI_1 sprite;
    private AI_2 sprite2;
    private AI_3 sprite3;
    private AI_4 sprite4;
    private Image image;
    private Image bg;
    private boolean ingame;

    public Board() {
        initBoard();
    }

    private void initBoard() {

        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setFocusable(true);

        start = new Start();
        ImageIcon bgi = new ImageIcon("back.jpg");
        bg = bgi.getImage();
        sprite = new AI_1(1200, 800);// passing actual parameter..or arguments
        sprite2 = new AI_2(0, 0);
        sprite3 = new AI_3(1200, 0);
        sprite4 = new AI_4(0, 800);
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
        timer.start();        
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

            if (ingame) {

                doDrawing(g);

            } else {

                drawGameOver(g);
            }

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        } 


    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);  
        g2d.drawImage(start.getImage(), start.getX(), start.getY(), this);  
        g2d.drawImage(sprite.getImage(), sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), this); 
        g2d.drawImage(sprite2.getImage(), sprite2.getX(), sprite2.getY(), this);
        g2d.drawImage(sprite3.getImage(), sprite3.getX(), sprite3.getY(), this);
        g2d.drawImage(sprite4.getImage(), sprite4.getX(), sprite4.getY(), this);
    }

    private void drawGameOver(Graphics g) {

        String msg = "Game Over";
        Font small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);
        FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(small);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(small);
        g.drawString(msg, (B_WIDTH - fm.stringWidth(msg)) / 2,
                B_HEIGHT / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        start.move();
        sprite.move();
        sprite2.move();
        sprite3.move();
        sprite4.move();
        repaint();  
    }

    public void checkCollisions() {

        Rectangle r3 = start.getBounds();
        Rectangle r2 = sprite.getBounds();
        Rectangle r1 = sprite2.getBounds();
        Rectangle r4 = sprite3.getBounds();
        Rectangle r5 = sprite4.getBounds();

            if (r3.intersects(r2)) {
                start.setVisible(false);
                sprite.setVisible(false);
                ingame = false;
            }
            if (r3.intersects(r1)) {
                start.setVisible(false);
                sprite2.setVisible(false);
                ingame = false;
            }
            if (r3.intersects(r4)) {
                start.setVisible(false);
                sprite3.setVisible(false);
                ingame = false;
            }
            if (r3.intersects(r5)) {
                start.setVisible(false);
                sprite4.setVisible(false);
                ingame = false;
            }
    }

    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            start.keyReleased(e);
            sprite.numbergen(4, 15); // direction and speed
            sprite2.numbergen(4, 15);
            sprite3.numbergen(4, 15);
            sprite4.numbergen(4, 15);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            start.keyPressed(e);
            sprite.numbergen(4, 10); // direction and speed
            sprite2.numbergen(4, 10);
            sprite3.numbergen(4, 10);
            sprite4.numbergen(4, 10);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think you will need a listener, which listens for positions of both user-image and CPU-image on the board. Listener is called whenever either of the image moves, but also checks, if there is a collision. Is there a method you have where you are detecting collision?

Comment: You need to minimise the code to the part where the problem is. If that error is fixed and there still are some errors make a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call checkCollisions() somewhere otherwise there wil be no checkCollisions

Comment: Yes, call checkCollisions() in update() method of your game loop.